# Why isn't $M = \{f(x) ∈ C^0(0,2): f(1) = 1\}$ a vector space over the real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Given the following two sets: $$M = \{f(x) ∈ C^0(0,2): f(1) = 1\}$$
$$S = \{f(x) ∈ C^0(0,2)\}$$

$C^0$ means a continuous real valued function.

Why is S a vector space over the real numbers, and not M?

$f(x) = x$, where $x ∈ (0,2)$ would be in both sets. All real numbers could be reached given the correct multiplier.

Comment: What would be the *zero vector* in $M$?

Comment: @mrf Couldn't you just multiply with zero? (0.5 * 0), since 0.5 is in the domain. If not, what would be the zero vector in S?

Comment: $f(1) = 1$ for all $f \in M$

Comment: @mrf I don't see how that is a problem, 1 is not the only number in the domain.

Comment: You know what a vector space is, right? There is no element $0$ in $M$ such that $f+0 = f$ for all $f \in M$.

Comment: @mrf Is there in S though?

Comment: Yes, the zero function: $0(x) = 0$ for all $x$ is in $S$.

Comment: @mrf That's true. Thank you!

Comment: If you figured everything out, considering writing an answer to the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A vector space has to satisfy some properties, the vector space axioms. One of these property is that, if $V$ is a vector space, then there exists an element denoted by $0$ so that $a+0=a$ for all $a \in V$.

In our case, you see that, as pointed out in the comments, no such element exists, for in $C^0(0,2)$ the zero element is defined to be a function:
$$z: (0, 2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto 0, \forall x \in (0,2).$$
It is clear by definition of $M$ that no such map is contained in it.